# Understanding GridBagLayout constraints

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I am relatively new to swing and I am trying to figure out exactly how it works. Tell me if I am wrong.

I have mostly figured out gridx and gridy which is necessary to place a component. You need at least n values of (gridx,gridy) to create an nxn grid. For example (5,5),(3,3),(4,9),(3,10) will create a 3x4 gridspace(4 rows, 3 columns) with the components using the above (gridx,gridy) respectively placed in cells (3,2),(1,2),(2,3),(1,4).

weightx and weighty seems to have 2 functions, a >0 value of weightx and weighy stretches the grid cells to the edges(otherwise it's centralised) and we can also set proportions to size of the component - so if one component has gridx=0.1 and anothr has 0.2, then the later one is likely to be twice as wide. However, while proportioning components, the minimum default width and height of a component is respected.

fill is required to stretch a component to the edges of the cells. Without fill, the component will remain at the center.

but we can use anchor in such cases to position the component say along the north west corner of the cell instead of center.

insets create a wall of space inside the edges of the cell.

ipadx and ipady pushes the boundaries of the column or row containing the cell.

**But** I am not able to figure out very well how gridwidth and gridheight works.

Consider this **example below**.Here 4 buttons are placed in cells b1(3,2),b2(1,1),b3(2,3),b4(4,4)
of 4x4 gridspace.

**How do I make the buttons , say b2 or b4, occupy the whole row or column of the cell that it is occupying?**

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
//import java.awt.event.*;
public class Swing29a
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
JFrame f1= new JFrame("GridBag Layout Test");

f1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
f1.setResizable(true);
f1.setLocation(200,100);
f1.setSize(800,800);

JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
p1.setBackground(Color.black);
f1.add(p1);


JButton b1= new JButton("Button 1");
b1.setBackground(Color.white);

JButton b2= new JButton("Button 2");
b2.setBackground(Color.white);

JButton b3= new JButton("Button 3");
b3.setBackground(Color.white);

JButton b4= new JButton("Button 4");
b4.setBackground(Color.white);



GridBagLayout gm1= new GridBagLayout();
p1.setLayout(gm1);
GridBagConstraints cns =new GridBagConstraints();

cns.gridx=5;
cns.gridy=5;
cns.weightx=0.1;
cns.weighty=0.1;
cns.fill=GridBagConstraints.BOTH;

p1.add(b1,cns);

cns.gridx=3;
cns.gridy=3;
p1.add(b2,cns);


cns.gridx=4;
cns.gridy=9;
p1.add(b3,cns);

cns.gridx=7;//3;
cns.gridy=10;
cns.gridheight=3;
cns.weightx=0.2;
cns.weighty=0.2;
//cns.weightx=10.0;
//cns.weighty=9.0;    
//cns.ipadx=50;
//cns.ipady=50;
p1.add(b4,cns);

f1.setVisible(true);

}
}
```

**EDIT:**
Here is a **LINK TO IMAGE**
http://postimg.org/image/wae2x4w4z/

I want any of the buttons to be able to fill the whole row or column, or take at least 2 cells in a row.

Comment: Adding a picture depicting your requirements will be much more helpful to understand your problem. Please make one, and link it to your question

Comment: 1) Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.  The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow. 2) Provide ASCII art of the GUI as it should appear in smallest size and (if resizable) with extra width/height.

Comment: gridWidth/gridHeight = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER

Comment: @sage : I don't have enough reputations to post a picture!

Comment: @Madprogrammer: Can you please modify the above code to make your point? I am unable to understand with just that one line. In fact, i have even tried GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER. It is not working!

Comment: user3015246 GBC column based LayoutManager, everything is about columns in 1st. row

Comment: @thanks for answering. Can you elaborate a little? I want something like this(sorry for bad drawing): postimg.org/image/7a5vi8t21

Answer (score 1):

**gridwidth, gridheight**:

Specify the number of columns (for gridwidth) or rows (for gridheight) in terms of `cells` the component's display area can be occupied by the component added with these constraint defined. The default value is `1`.

So, If for a grid of (`R x C`); there are `C` number of cells in a row. If you want to have a component to occupy all the cell of that specific row, just set the `GridBigConstraint.gridWidth` to `C`.

Use `GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER` to specify that the component be the last one in its row (for gridwidth) or column (for gridheight).

There is already a nice written example in the tutorial: [How to use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer,Sage. But it doesn't solve my problem. I have given the FULL code. Why don't you run it and then post a modified code?

Comment: @user3015246, upload the image to a hosting site and link it to your question. We will attach it for you

Comment: OK, wait a minute please

Comment: I have seen it and checked. But my question is that why you are even specifying the cell randomly ?

Comment: what do you mean randomly?

Comment: You should add your component specifying the grid from left to right and top to bottom. gridx: 0 ---> col, gridy: 0 ----> row. But you have specified randomly, `(3, 3)`, `(5, 5)`, `(7, 10)` and such. It makes the code less readable and harder to understand the layout sequence

Comment: I understand, I was just kinda experimenting with gridbag layout. I don't think numbering in order from (0,0) will make that much difference. Will it?

Comment: yes it will in lots of way. Do it with maintaining the sequence and you will find that everything will work as you were expecting it.

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like this...

[image]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class GridBagTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame f1 = new JFrame("GridBag Layout Test");

        f1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f1.setResizable(true);
        f1.setLocation(200, 100);
        f1.setSize(800, 800);

        JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
        p1.setBackground(Color.black);
        f1.add(p1);

        JButton b1 = new JButton("Button 1");
        b1.setBackground(Color.white);

        JButton b2 = new JButton("Button 2");
        b2.setBackground(Color.white);

        JButton b3 = new JButton("Button 3");
        b3.setBackground(Color.white);

        JButton b4 = new JButton("Button 4");
        b4.setBackground(Color.white);

        GridBagLayout gm1 = new GridBagLayout();
        p1.setLayout(gm1);
        GridBagConstraints cns = new GridBagConstraints();

        cns.gridx = 5;
        cns.gridy = 5;
        cns.weightx = 0.1;
        cns.weighty = 0.1;
        cns.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;

        p1.add(b1, cns);

        cns.gridx = 3;
        cns.gridy = 3;
//        cns.gridheight = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
        cns.gridwidth = 3;
        p1.add(b2, cns);

        cns.gridheight = 1;
        cns.gridwidth = 1;
        cns.gridx = 4;
        cns.gridy = 9;
        p1.add(b3, cns);

        cns.gridx = 6;
        cns.gridy = 3;
        cns.gridheight = 7;
        cns.weightx = 0.2;
        cns.weighty = 0.2;
//        cns.gridheight = 4;
        p1.add(b4, cns);

        f1.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

`gridwidth` basically tells `GridBagLayout` how many columns a component should expand across (the default being 1).  This will always expand right.

`gridheight` does the same, expect that it will always expand down...

**Updated**

`GridBagLayout` is very powerful, but even then, sometimes, it has limitations.

To achieve something like...

[image]

The simplest choice is to addd a "filler" component, for example...

```
cns.gridx = 3;
cns.gridy = 9;
cns.gridwidth = 1;
JPanel pnl = new JPanel();
pnl.setOpaque(false);
p1.add(pnl, cns);
```

Comment: The problem with the OP's code is that his specification of cell using gridx and gridy is a little out of my mind :(

Comment: @madprogrammer : Yes, that is exactly the type I want. What was wrong with my code?

Comment: wait, I think you changed the position of button4. And button1 too. That's not exactly what I wanted.

Comment: Basically, `btn4` was positioned at the bottom of the column, in order to fill the column, it needs to placed at the top.  You then need to supply appropriate `gridWidth` and `gridHeight` values so that they fill the appropriate number of columns and rows. Remember, a row or column with nothing in it will still need to be included, even though it has no size...

Comment: *"wait, I think you changed the position of button4. That's not exactly what I wanted"* - If you want this effect, you have no choice, this is how it works...you will have to adapt.  You can't tell `GridBagLayout` to fill backwards, only forwards...

Comment: I see. Thanks. But why did you change the position of button1? SORRY, not buton1, button2

Comment: As near as I can tell, every thing else is in the same position btn1 is at 5x5, btn2 is at 3x3 and btn3 is at 4x9...

Comment: b2 was at the top left corner, and not over b1 or b3 in my picture.

Comment: It still is, but now it expands 3 columns...Thought that's what you wanted?  If you want to to expand all the rows, you could get rid of the grid width and replace it with something like `cns.gridheight = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER`, but you'll have to move `btn4` up one row and adjust it's `gridheight` to compensate, or use `GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER` as well...

Comment: @sage The requirements are little vague :P

Comment: @MadProgrammer: My problem is that b2 has x=3 and b3 has x=4, so why does b2 not start from the left of b3. Why does b2  start from same x as b3?

Comment: I want something like more or less like this(sorry for bad drawing):

http://postimg.org/image/7a5vi8t21/

Comment: This has to do with the fact that empty rows/columns are collapsed automatically....

Comment: @MadProgrammer : Thanks for clarifying that. I think it's also starting to make sense. I finally managed to create something like the image above see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I said I want something like more or less like this:
http://postimg.org/image/7a5vi8t21/

and thanks to all the clarifications I am able to do more or less that.
I used an extra transparent button.
here is the ouput image:
http://postimg.org/image/6yw3c8b37/

and below is the code

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
//import java.awt.event.*;

public class GridBagTest2 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame f1 = new JFrame("GridBag Layout Test");

        f1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f1.setResizable(true);
        f1.setLocation(200, 100);
        f1.setSize(800, 800);

        JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
        p1.setBackground(Color.black);
        f1.add(p1);

        JButton b1 = new JButton("Button 1");
        b1.setBackground(Color.white);

        JButton b2 = new JButton("Button 2");
        b2.setBackground(Color.white);

        JButton b3 = new JButton("Button 3");
        b3.setBackground(Color.white);

        JButton b4 = new JButton("Button 4");
        b4.setBackground(Color.white);

        JButton b5 = new JButton("        ");
        b5.setBackground(Color.white);
        b5.setBorderPainted(false);
        b5.setOpaque(false);

        JLabel lb1 = new JLabel("");
        //lb1.setOpaque(true);

        GridBagLayout gm1 = new GridBagLayout();
        p1.setLayout(gm1);
        GridBagConstraints cns = new GridBagConstraints();

        cns.gridx = 5;
        cns.gridy = 5;
        cns.weightx = 0.1;
        cns.weighty = 0.1;
        cns.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;

        p1.add(b1, cns);

        cns.gridx = 3;
        cns.gridy = 3;

        cns.gridwidth = 3;
        p1.add(b2, cns);

        cns.gridheight = 1;
        cns.gridwidth = 1;
        cns.gridx = 4;
        cns.gridy = 9;
        p1.add(b3, cns);

        cns.gridx = 7;
        cns.gridy = 3;
        cns.gridheight = 8;
        cns.weightx = 0.2;
        cns.weighty = 0.2;

        p1.add(b4, cns);


        cns.gridx = 3;
        cns.gridy = 10;
        cns.gridheight=1;
        cns.gridwidth = 1;
        cns.weightx = 0.1;
        cns.weighty = 0.1;
        p1.add(b5, cns);


        f1.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

I think I am finally understanding how gridwidth and gridheight works. They work from left to right and top to down. They also collapse in the absense of supporting components in empty rows or columns.

however, there are still some questions I don't understand. If I use a transparent label (lb1) instead of the transparent button b5, the dimension of the column changes. Also, why is b4 not twice as wide as the other buttons despite having twice the weight?